# Sorting by slice fields

Tags: go

I have the following Structs:

```
type Parent struct {
    id       string
    children []Child
}

type Child struct {
    id string
}
```

I have made a slice of Parents with the following values:

```
parents := make([]Parent, 0)

p1 := Parent {
    "3",
    []Child {
        {"2"},
        {"3"},
        {"1"},
    },
}

p2 := Parent {
    "1",
    []Child {
        {"8"},
        {"9"},
        {"7"},
    },
}

p3 := Parent {
    "2",
    []Child {
        {"5"},
        {"6"},
        {"4"},
    },
}             

parents = append(parents, p1, p2, p3)
```

I am trying to sort the "parents" slice in the following order:

```
1) First, sort all Parents by Parent.id

2) Next, sort each Parent's "children" slice by Child.id
```

The expected result is something like:

```
[{1 [{7} {8} {9}]} {2 [{4} {5} {6}]} {3 [{1} {2} {3}]}]
```

Is there a way to do this in Go?

Comment: Yes and it so dead simple: 1) You sort the slice of Parents by Parent.id and 2) You sort each Parents children by their Child.Id. As you described the algorithm already in the question I'm unsure what you are asking for. Sorting in your case is probably done via sort.Slice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work using the following code:

```
// sort each Parent in the parents slice by Id
sort.Slice(parents, func(i, j int) bool {return parents[i].id < parents[j].id})

// for each Parent, sort each Child in the children slice by Id
for _, parent := range parents {
    sort.Slice(parent.children, func(i, j int) bool {return parent.children[i].id < parent.children[j].id})
}
```

Special thanks to @Volker for mentioning the ***sort.Slice*** function! I had no idea it existed!

Comment: That function exists since Go 1.8, it's brand new :)